# Who is this character depicted in the holograms in Thor: Ragnarok?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In **Thor: Ragnarok**, when *Scrapper-142* captures Thor on Sakaar and he's being prepared to be presented to The Grandmaster, Thor is taken through a "presentation" of sorts giving him a background about where he is. During this, a hologram shows a two-headed champion fighting (*below is the screen-shot*).

[image]
 <sub>*Image from **Thor: Ragnarok (2017)***</sub>

Following the answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173708/who-is-depicted-in-the-statues-on-the-grandmasters-palace-in-thor-ragnarok) on various champions depicted on the Grandmaster's palace, this fighter doesn't seem to be Bi-beast.

[image]

So, **who is this fighter/champion?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This ***three***-headed character is named Haju and was a last-minute addition to the film (and also a cameo for the director). Chris Hemsworth and Luke Hemsworth(?) play the other two heads.

> Everyone knows that Taika plays Korg, the scene-stealing bag of rocks.
> But he also technically cameos as two others. *“I am one of the heads
> on the three-headed alien, this character called Haju* [this may not be
> correct spelling],” says Waititi. *“I'm the head on the right. And I'm
> also the motion-capture for Surtur,"* the fire demon who ultimately
> destroys Asgard (though Clancy Brown provides Surtur’s voice).
>
> <sub><sup>[Thor: Ragnarok – 12 Revelations From Director Taika Waititi](https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/thor-ragnarok-12-revelations-director-taika-waititi/)</sup></sub>

You see him (them?) on the left in the scene where Korg frees the slaves.

[image]

He appears to have died in the final battle, fighting to allow the Asgardian population to board the ship.

Comment: A short glimpse during the hologram scene showed only two heads so I assumed he was someone completely different. But now that you mention it, it does seem plausible than what I’d thought before.

Comment: The blue stripes across the nose and forehead seem to be distinguishable and matching in both the holo and the screencap in this answer.